# How to link get focus after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, css

My problem is this: When I click in a button and then refresh the page, I want my menu clear the previous visited links (turning them to normal again), but keeping the current visited link as a:visited in css.

I think it is simple, but I am beginning in web programming, so I need help. I have found a way to make this. But the problem is it is not working!! This is the code that I have:

```
< ul id="menuTop">
  < li id="menu-link-1">
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", null, null, new { id = "link-1-visited" }) < /li>
< li id="menu-link-2">
@Html.ActionLink("Produtos", "Products", null, null, new { id = "link-2-visited" })  < /li>
< li id="menu-link-3">
@Html.ActionLink("Fale Conosco", "ContactUs", null, null, new { id = "link-3-visited" })  < /li>
< li id="menu-link-4">
@Html.ActionLink("Quem Somos", "AboutUs", null, null, new { id = "link-4-visited" })  < /li>
< /ul>
```

This is my buttons, and the code to make them "visited" is that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#link-1-visited').click(function() {
    $("#menu-link-1").removeAttr("menu-link-1");
    $(this).addClass('link-1-visited');
    window.alert("test 1 !!");
});

$('#link-2-visited').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('link-1-visited');
    window.alert("test 2 !!");
});

$('#link-3-visited').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('link-1-visited');
    window.alert("test 3 !!");
});

$('#link-4-visited').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('link-1-visited');
    window.alert("test 4 !!");
});
});
```

My code in css is:

```
ul#menuTop li#menu-link-1 a {
    background-image: url("../Content/images/Menu/menu-image-1-alt.png");
    margin-right: 1px;
}

ul#menuTop li#menu-link-1 a:hover {
    background-image: url("../Content/images/Menu/menu-image-1-hover.png");
    margin-right: 1px;
}

.link-1-visited {
    padding: 40px 20px 20px;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    // more styles below...
}

ul#menuTop li a {
    border: 3px #98fb98 solid;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    //more styles below...
}

ul#menuTop li a:hover {
    padding: 40px 20px 20px;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    //more styles below...
}
```

The problem is my code in menu-link-1 is not working. I want to remove the ul and li css and add class "link-1-visited" to it.

Do you have any ideas about how can I do that?

Comment: there is no way of doing this with css alone. since the browser decides what links are visited, and what aren't.

Comment: you can style each link similarly. Record which links are visited in local storage and store a pageview count. Set it to zero for each link that gets clicked on the first time. Increment all existing links. The ones above 1 are removed. The ones in local storage can be styled differently

Comment: Like I said, I'm new in this web development. Can you show me some tutorial?

Comment: m not sure anybody's actually done this. there's nt much value in it. I just thought up the solution randomly. It will take a lot of time to implement

Comment: btw why do you need this? Do u have a specific case why you need this. There might be other ways of doing it

Comment: Ohh, great! I just wanna do that to my site be more presentable. Can you show me other ways to do that?

Comment: Okay. Its not worth the effort to do it this way. Suppose the user comes back 2 days later and wants to see what pages he has visited in the past and can only see those that he say on the last visit. After refresh, teh whole thing is lost again. He'll be clueless if he was relying on the link color to determine which page on your site he shud visit next.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to set your links to stay one color in your css, so ...

```
a, a:visited { 
    color: blue;
}
```

And then you just change the color with jQuery on the click event:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    ($this).css({"color":"white"});
});
```

Just change the values to fit what you are using and you should be all set.

For what your trying to do, look into session variables here: [Java session variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339531/java-session-variables)

Comment: The problem of this method is when the page refreshes, the button turn to normal again. I want it get the focus and keep with it when I refresh the page.

Comment: Sorry, I had misunderstood what you wrote. You won't be able to do this with jQuery because all of the variables you set will clear when you refresh the page. If you have an application back-end you can look into server side variables which wont be cleared until you restart the service or the server. I have updated my answer above with a link.

Answer (score 0):

```js
/* change the id name according to the page link you want to make focused */
var page = document.getElementById("index").href;
if (page == index) {
  document.getElementById("index").className = "active";
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 13.8px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #555555;
  font-style: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: background-color .4s;
}

.active {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: rgb(255, 204, 65);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a id="index" href="index.html">Overview</a></li>
  <li><a id="wed" href="wed.html">Wedding</a></li>
  <li><a id="engage" href="engage.html">Engagement</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.